# How to insert a PHP CODE inside shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I would like to insert a php code, but the error when placing

**Shortcode generated by theme**

```
[col_grid span="4" span__sm="14" height="1-2" visibility="show-for-medium"]

[ux_banner height="500px" bg="***[banner-picture]***" bg_size="original"]

[text_box width="100" scale="148" position_x="50" position_y="100" bg="rgb(88, 32, 123)"]

[ux_text text_color="rgb(247, 128, 44)" class="uppercase"]

<p><strong>preencha a proposta de adesão</strong></p>
[/ux_text]

[/text_box]

[/ux_banner]

[/col_grid]
```

---

**My PHP CODE**

```
add_action('foto_banner', 10 );
  
function foto_banner() { ?>
<?php if(get_field('foto_banner')) { ?>


<?php the_field('foto_banner'); ?>

<?php }else{
    echo "Texto não informado";
}
}

add_shortcode( 'banner-picture', 'foto_banner');
```

Comment: you may need to make a shortcode that wraps everything then runs `do_shortcode` on it again, presuming its not erroring

Answer (score 1):

You can write your shortcode like this:

```
<?php

function bannerPicture(){
    ob_start();

    if( get_field( 'foto_banner' ) ) {
        the_field( 'foto_banner' );
    } else {
        echo "Texto não informado";
    }

    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
    
}
add_shortcode( 'banner-picture', 'bannerPicture' );

?>
```

Make sure to add current page id in `get_field()` second parameter or `option` if you are fetching from Theme Options page.

Comment: See this short vídeo: https://www.loom.com/share/e87f5d599a2244019c032e0c63f74c92

Comment: I use your code, but not working

Comment: HI @GabrielLapa it is just a reference for your shortcode. You have to implement the logic according to your requirements. 

I just checked your video.

By default, WordPress doesn't allow you to use a shortcode within a shortcode (or in other words, nested shortcode)

Answer (score 0):

You can not put PHP functions inside your shortcode.

However, you do not need to. You can just use your foreach-loop to create the html and store it in a variable, for example $shortcodehtml.

So, afterwards, you can call

```
echo do_shortcode('[O_U user_name="operator" blocked_message="This page is restricted for guests."]' . $shortcodehtml . '[/O_U]');
```

The better version of that would be if you would create the output inside the shortcode function - from my point of view it is not necessary to pass the whole html to the shortcode - but this should work fine.

Comment: See this short vídeo: https://www.loom.com/share/e87f5d599a2244019c032e0c63f74c92

Answer (score 0):

you need to creates an output buffer

```
function shortcode_func()
{
    ob_start();
    ?>
    // PHP codes...
    global $variable;
    require_once("/dir/file.php");

    ?>

    <!-- HTML... -->
    <div> Hello World </div> 

    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('shortcode', 'shortcode_func');
```